# Intercepting form_for submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Short: How can I intercept the value of a form_for select to modify the value being sent to the server on submit?

Full version: I have a form_for inside a partial for an object with an ext_id attribute (it's the default _form partial generated by scaffold).

I've modified it as follows: there are 2 selects in the form (A and B). B is hidden by default. A can only be true or false. If A is true ext_id must be set to a default value X. If user selects false on A, B appears and then ext_id is set according to B value (I've used jQuery for that).

Now the problem is: if the form is used for creation ext_id is set to B value if A is false and it's unset if A is true. I guess I could use some kind of ActiveRecord validation to set it to the default value if it's unset in this case, BUT, I if it's being used for edit and I change A to hide B, B old value is still selected, so ext_id never changes to "unset".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is much easier than it looks. The scaffold generator creates 2 actions in the controller for both create (new and create) and edit (edit and update). The first is used to generate the form and the other to process it, so it's as easy as doing whatever you want with the submitted data when you receive it on create/update.

Comment: Of course, you can do that. With my solution, the advantage is that you only do `@model.save`. The controller does not have to know how `ext_id` has been provided in the view. It' more MVC like.

Comment: Well, as I see it, the MVC model supports my solution. The view doesn't need/have to know what this ext_id is at all :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I wouldn't use select A or B to submit the data to the form. I'd use them only to set the value of a hidden field in jQuery. I guess you know how to do that.

```
f.hidden_field :ext_id, :value => "default_value"

$('#your_model_ext_id').val(...the value from A or B selects...)
```

Comment: Nice workaround, I'm giving you an upvote. However I found the "pure" solution, I answered myself :)

Comment: Thanks for the vote (I can't see it). I commented below on your solution.